# QGIS Shape File Saving Error

Tags: sql, qgis

I am tasked to display and save a geometry table as a shape file in which it is properly being displayed in QGIS with properties of Selected CRS. However , i am unable to save this file as a shapefile and keep having the error , 
Export to vector file filed and it is unable to write the features in. The following error is shown :

```
Export to vector file failed.
Error: Feature write errors:
Feature geometry not imported (OGR error: )
Feature geometry not imported (OGR error: ) 
Feature geometry not imported (OGR error: )
Feature geometry not imported (OGR error: )
Feature geometry not imported (OGR error: )
Feature geometry not imported (OGR error: )
.....
Feature geometry not imported (OGR error: )
Only 0 of 24 features written.
```

I have come across many sources on this error , i have tried changing the CRS to projected but it doesn't appear. i have also tried converting the multi polygon Zm data type to point but i think i require more suggestions on the query because i tried St_X , ST_Y, ST_Transform but to no avail
The following data is an example :

```
name, geom  
A   ,01060000C00100000001030000C00100000006000000F003BAE509B0B4C03075928D3794AD400000000000000000000000000000000010476358074AB4C0C0C4357A41338E40000000000000000000000000000000000873A79418D9BAC0C04D20C989348E40000000000000000000000000000000008036289611D9BAC0807B (...)
b   ,01060000C00100000001030000C00100000006000000F003BAE509B0B4C03075928D3794AD400000000000000000000000000000000010476358074AB4C0C0C4357A41338E40000000000000000000000000000000000873A79418D9BAC0C04D20C989348E40000000000000000000000000000000008036289611D9BAC0807B (...)
```

Any suggestion would be welcome. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe try posting this as a bug to hub.qgis.org

Comment: i cant access the account because its under company :( any suggestion on the problem ? it seems like a pretty rare issue